# Ant Design V5 causing flash unstyled component at first load

Tags: next.js, antd, server-side-rendering

The problem is very similar to the problem years back. Below are the link to navigate to the discussion.

[Github Discussion](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/16037)

I'm using `Next.js 13` and `Ant Design V5`, ant design component will have flash unstyled component at first load. After that it will back to normal, according to the discussion, seems like is the SSR issue.

Other than using the solutions inside the discussion, any perfect solution to solve it?

- Disabled SSR, it's work but seems like not a perfect solution.
- `visibility: hidden` until the `useEffect` set the `mount state` to true, not working, animation still there.
- Disabled the animation, animation is not there anymore but it still convert from unstyled to styled component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.onload = () => {
            document.getElementById('holderStyle')!.remove();
        };
    }

    return (
        <ConfigProvider>
            <style
                id="holderStyle"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                    *, *::before, *::after {
                        transition: none!important;
                    }
                    `,
                }}
            />
            <div style={{ visibility: !mounted ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </div>
        </ConfigProvider>
    );
}
```

After tested it one by one, so far this is the solution I found to solve the issue without disabling the `SSR`.

Answer (score 0):

https://ant.design/docs/react/server-side-rendering

Make sure to cache extract style in SSR then the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problems, but solved by checkout their updated doc [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next/)

It works with me with app folder